# Como acessar as variáveis de um escopo anterior em PHP?

Tags: php, escopo-de-variáveis

Primeiramente, dentro de uma classe eu tenho um método, nesse método eu tenho um parâmetro (por enquanto) e declaro algumas variáveis em seu escopo. Portanto, também declaro funções dentro do escopo do método, e como todos sabem, toda função tem seu próprio escopo.

O problema é que no escopo das funções que eu declarei no escopo do método as variáveis que declarei anteriormente são indefinidas, e por isso não posso acessá-las. Como posso contornar isso? Preciso acessar as variáveis do escopo anterior no escopo dessas funções.

Essa é uma parte da função que tenho em minha classe, é aí que estou tendo problemas.

```
public static function parse($buf) {
    $i = 0; $chr; $cod;

    // $i, $chr, $cod e $buf
    // são todas invisíveis no escopo das funções abaixo.

    /* Iterate each char in $buf. */
    function itchr($c) {
        for (; $chr = $buf[$i]; ++$i) {
            $cod = getchrcode($chr);
            if ($c() === false)
                break;
        }
    }

    /* Consume $buf string until $c returns truth value. */
    function consumetil($c) {
        $result = (object) array(
            "matched" => false,
            "value" => ""
        );

        for (; $chr = $buf[$i]; ++$i) {
            $cod = getchrcode($chr);
            if ($c()) {
                $result->matched = true;
                break;
            } else $result->value .= $chr;
        }

        return $result;
    }

    /* Consume a little identifier in $buf */
    function consumeid() {
        return consumetil(function() {
            return !isIdentifierPart($cod);
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Herde as variáveis do *escopo pai* com [**funções anônimas** (*`closures`*)](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/functions.anonymous.php), referenciando pelo ***comando*** [**use**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/functions.anonymous.php).

***Exemplo:***

```
$message = "hi !!!";
$example = function () use ($message) {
    var_dump($message);
};
$example();
```

Eu faria mais simples, colocaria as variáveis locais como `private` `static` e faria o acesso com `self`:

**Exemplo:**

```
class g 
{
    private static $message = "Bom dia";
    public static function aa()
    {
        self::$message .= " a nós todos";
        return self::$message;
    }
    public static function getMessage()
    {
        return self::$message;  
    }
}

echo g::aa(); //Bom dia a nós todos
echo '<br>';
echo g::getMessage(); //Bom dia a nós todos
```

[Exemplo Funcional](http://ideone.com/fork/wX5QSR)

---

```
public static function parse($buf) {
    private static $i = 0; 
    private static $chr; 
    private static $cod;

    // $i, $chr, $cod e $buf
    // são todas invisíveis no escopo das funções abaixo.

    /* Iterate each char in $buf. */
    function itchr($c) {
        for (; self::$chr = $buf[self::$i]; ++$i) {
            self::$cod = getchrcode(self::$chr);
            if ($c() === false)
                break;
        }
    }

    /* Consume $buf string until $c returns truth value. */
    function consumetil($c) {
        $result = (object) array(
            "matched" => false,
            "value" => ""
        );

        for (; $chr = $buf[self::$i]; ++self::$i) {
            self::$cod = getchrcode(self::$chr);
            if ($c()) {
                $result->matched = true;
                break;
            } else $result->value .= self::$chr;
        }

        return $result;
    }

    /* Consume a little identifier in $buf */
    function consumeid() {
        return consumetil(function() {
            return !isIdentifierPart(self::$cod);
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: @TheProHands você quer passar por referencia dentro `use`?

Comment: Sim, também esqueci de avisar, o PHP não aceita o uso da palavra-chave `'use'` quando o nome da função foi declarado, por isso não funciona fazer isso normalmente no meu código. Primeiramente tive que transformar minhas funções em variáveis, como no seu primeiro exemplo. Ou seja, o exemplo de implementação de `use` na resposta não funciona.

Comment: @TheProHands verdade !!! eu até removi da resposta e se você usar só `self::`?

Comment: `self` seria uma referência para a instância da classe, certo? E `::` é só uma forma de indexar? Não sou muito experiente em PHP, por isso pergunto.

Comment: Isso `self` seria o acesso as métodos ou variaveis `static`

Comment: @TheProHands eu fiz mais edições com `static` seria assim. Você não poderia usar esse código da forma de instâncias?

Comment: Eu também pensei nisso, mas acho que faria uma perda de performance já que teria que ficar fazendo lookup para `"self"` repetidamente. Eu posso usar `self::` futuramente em outras classes já que essa seria para interpretar uma string

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46161/discussion-between-virgilio-novic-and-the-pro-hands).